# How to use value from...to as user input?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that modifies a chart layout, using a chart number that has to be modified as user input value. As far i have a lot of charts (about 50), i would like to imput not just 1 value per time, but to say to modify charts for example from 2 to 10. Can some one help with it, please?

```
Sub Grafici()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sUserInput As String
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Select

    sUserInput = InputBox("Enter Number:", "Collect User Input")

    For i = 1 To 7
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart " & sUserInput).Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(12).MarkerSize = 19
        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(11).DataLabel.Delete
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(i).Points(11).MarkerSize = 5
                Next
    End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: will the charts to be modified always be a continuous range (2 to 10), or could they be (2,5,7,10)?

Comment: could be both, also (2,5,7,10)

Comment: Set chart object into a variable rather than using `activechart` to improve your code. It's not the answer to your question though. What is this doing? `ws.Select`

Comment: ws.Select, to define the right sheet as far there are many

Comment: I think your first task then is to collect multiple inputs from the user. either use a user form, or ask user to separate by '/' or something in the input box, or you could just loop the thing code as it is, asking user for a new input on each cycle until they type 'exit' or something.

Comment: Simply use another sheet to allow user to enter the inputs by chart name or id. Read that range and inject into the charts. That won't be as too painful or blind-stoning as iterative-user-inputs via input boxes... *e.g. if one goes wrong in the niput collection iteration, then? all wrong*...

Comment: i've got it, thanks. in case of continuous rage, does it somehow simplifies the task?